# Lightdm is not changing background on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, gnome, login, lightdm, desktop-background

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 and right away installed Unity and configured lightdm instead of gdm and then removed gnome-shell while in unity enviornment.

Since then no problem except lightdm won't change background according to the wallpaper. There is also no more guest account option.

How to change the lightdm background or make it adapt to the current wallpaper? I'm **not** looking for moving my wallpaper folder to /usr/share/background for the adapting part. It's obviously stuck somehow because it was fine in 16.04.3. And the /home is not encrypted either.

Comment: Are you trying to change the background to a single default image or do you want a background that changes on a per-user basis?

Comment: For a single default image, [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/694370/8005) worked for me using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: And can we make it like it was in 16.04? which was always adapting to the user's choice of desktop background?

Comment: Related question: [User background/wallpaper on login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1051910/8005)

Comment: [This article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/ubuntu-guest-sessions-login-disabled) says Canonical disabled per-user backgrounds because of a security issue. The same security update disabled guest login.

Comment: What a bummer. They should have fixed it instead of altogether removing it. Anyways, doing as the the previous link hampers those security in question?

Comment: You can [set a single default image](https://askubuntu.com/a/694370/8005) without opening a security vulnerability (AFAIK). [Enabling guest login](https://askubuntu.com/q/1051910/8005) would (I think) expose the vulnerability, at least for now.

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

create `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override`

with content

```
[com.canonical.unity-greeter] 
draw-user-backgrounds=false
background='/foo/wallpaper.png'
```

And run `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` to apply these settings.

Adjust to your needs.